# How to Map Week number with each day of the week in Hive

Tags: apache-spark-sql, hive, impala

I have a Week table where Week number, start and end date of that week information is present and a daily sales tables which have sales information at day level.
In sales table I want to include week number so that data can be aggregated at week level

I tried below join and it didnt work for me

```
create table sales_day (
day int,
sales int
);

insert into sales_day
select 1, 5
union
select 2, 10   
union
select 3, 2     
union
select 4, 1      
union
select 5, 8     
union
select 6, 7 ;

create table week_num (
wk string,
day_start int,
day_end int);

insert into week_num
select 'w1', 1, 5
union
select 'w2', 6, 10 ;

I tried join and cross join to get week number into sales table, used below query but it is returning 0 records

select x.wk,  t.* from sales_day t join week_num x
where x.day_start >= t.`day` and
x.day_end <= t.`day`;
```

please let me know what is wrong in this join condition.

From the week_num table is it possible to split all days of the week in Hive using week number and start and end day columns
(Is it possible to generate data in below format)
Eg :

| week_num | day |
| --- | --- |
| w1 | 1 |
| w1 | 2 |
| w1 | 3 |
| w1 | 4 |
| w1 | 5 |
| w2 | 6 |